# Grouping SQL recordset by/into alphabetical order with a letter range

Tags: mysql, grouping, alphabetical

Normally I'd do my homework properly first, but I'm up against a deadline now and thought I'd throw this out there for some help, mainly because I know from previous experience anything I think is complex is actually a breeze for SQL.

I'm looking to group my results by a letter range, not just an individual letter. So, ultimately I'd like my output to be something like

```
ABCD:
-- Alpha
-- Bravo
-- Charlie
-- Delta

EFGH:
-- Echo
-- Foxtrot
-- Gulf
-- Hotel
```

Until now I've been using `ORDER BY LOWER(name) ASC` and then just copying records into an array structure to get the single letter grouping (A, B, C, etc.), but that would need expanding to group by a letter range, and I'm wondering it there's a faster/more efficient way of doing it.

Pure SQL solution? Or post-processing in PHP?

Tips, tricks, full answers appreciated as always.

Comment: Can't you just `ORDER BY name` and "group" the results in your application (PHP) code? I don't see a need to use `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Unless you only want counts (`ABCD : 4`, `EFGH : 4`, `IJKL : 0`, ..., `YZ : 0`)

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand how you're "grouping" them in SQL since you still have to list them in alphabetical order.

Comment: I've not said anywhere that I'm using GROUP BY - @ypercube: I'm already using ORDER BY name to get the results and then using PHP to bunch the records together under a single-letter group. I was just wondering if there's anything in SQL that would speed up the process for me instead of writing more PHP to bunch records under a letter range.

Comment: I don't see anything that could do such a thing. To be honest I can't see what "such a thing" would be. Your rows are returned from MySQL in the order you want. With "bunching" I guess you mean the splitting or rows into groups and putting a header before each group. This would be a simple check in PHP (previous row vs. current row).

Comment: And you do say *"but that would need expanding to **group by** a letter range"* which may confused us on your intend.

Comment: yeah, bad phrasing on my part - not quite as eloquent and descriptive as usual given I'm rushing around like a maniac. I'll just do my actual grouping up in PHP - cheers for the input peeps

Answer (score 0):

It's a little ugly, but try using UNION like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 'ABCD' AS myGroup, name FROM users WHERE LEFT(name,1) IN ('A','B','C','D')
    UNION
    SELECT 'EFGH' AS myGroup, name FROM users WHERE LEFT(name,1) IN ('E','F','G','H')
    UNION
    SELECT 'IJKL' AS myGroup, name FROM users WHERE LEFT(name,1) IN ('I','J','K','L')
    UNION
    SELECT 'MNOP' AS myGroup, name FROM users WHERE LEFT(name,1) IN ('M','N','O','P')
    UNION
    SELECT 'QRST' AS myGroup, name FROM users WHERE LEFT(name,1) IN ('Q','R','S','T')
    UNION
    SELECT 'UVWX' AS myGroup, name FROM users WHERE LEFT(name,1) IN ('U','V','W','X')
    UNION
    SELECT 'YZ' AS myGroup, name FROM users WHERE LEFT(name,1) IN ('Y','Z')
) AS myResults ORDER BY mygroup,name
```

Adding a little to GROUP BY will give you aggregate results like COUNT:

```
SELECT myGroup, COUNT(name) as myGroupCount FROM (
    SELECT 'ABCD' AS myGroup, name FROM users WHERE LEFT(name,1) IN ('A','B','C','D')
    UNION
    SELECT 'EFGH' AS myGroup, name FROM users WHERE LEFT(name,1) IN ('E','F','G','H')
    UNION
    SELECT 'IJKL' AS myGroup, name FROM users WHERE LEFT(name,1) IN ('I','J','K','L')
    UNION
    SELECT 'MNOP' AS myGroup, name FROM users WHERE LEFT(name,1) IN ('M','N','O','P')
    UNION
    SELECT 'QRST' AS myGroup, name FROM users WHERE LEFT(name,1) IN ('Q','R','S','T')
    UNION
    SELECT 'UVWX' AS myGroup, name FROM users WHERE LEFT(name,1) IN ('U','V','W','X')
    UNION
    SELECT 'YZ' AS myGroup, name FROM users WHERE LEFT(name,1) IN ('Y','Z')
) AS myResults GROUP BY mygroup ORDER BY mygroup,name
```